# Cassandra File too Large Error on Start Up

Tags: cassandra

When restarting a node in my cluster I sometimes get this error message

```
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-04-12 19:32:53,574 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
ERROR [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2016-04-12 20:02:15,636 CassandraDaemon.java:195 - Exception in thread Thread[HintsWriteExecutor:1,5,main]
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: bin/../data/hints/389cb0d3-87b9-4221-8352-065e8ce50fdb-1460462523225-1.crc32: File too large
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriter.writeChecksum(HintsWriter.java:116) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriter.close(HintsWriter.java:124) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsStore.closeWriter(HintsStore.java:201) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: bin/../data/hints/389cb0d3-87b9-4221-8352-065e8ce50fdb-1460462523225-1.crc32: File too large
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriter.writeChecksum(HintsWriter.java:110) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
```

The node then starts shutting down, but gets stuck repeated throwing an exception and retrying every few seconds. This is the main problem for me because it stopped the cluster from accepting connections

```
ERROR [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2016-04-12 20:02:15,638 StorageService.java:440 - Stopping gossiper
WARN  [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2016-04-12 20:02:15,651 StorageService.java:347 - Stopping gossip by operator request
INFO  [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2016-04-12 20:02:15,651 Gossiper.java:1455 - Announcing shutdown
DEBUG [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2016-04-12 20:02:15,653 StorageService.java:1921 - Node /169.34.103.150 state shutdown, token [-1028691827956217809, -1257393635657191129, -1285475466194230655, -1398822673992383910, -1549844858878358481, -1638651369075180065, -1660825917518666149, -1802478872312866489, -1834618755337322564, -188187624477415935, -2034018930607672685, -210049110249018365, -2157250079133002505, -2171215058533514263, -2183510006393476006, -2193567329545672696, -2317710820662725097, -2319735333341559730, -2333531623390263516, -2458839661565177963, -2489690089103800827, -2710032230533922787, -2780200665893123668, -283628639049224915, -2886550293705646069, -293132189636842303, -2945647150702034785, -2965944925251907629, -2990231874502594267, -2991676811317743630, -2997538046339800243, -3176643432551515484, -3176889844544735478, -3201806929871841501, -3211631881211211792, -322057073400957538, -3242716520974847469, -3424682940569182570, -3441313897213257083, -3448874645237774640, -3452014929671888774, -3487048220426765500, -3523033168154067409, -3738270231064896111, -3792947624538231469, -3850123184653095411, -3859434367535677710, -3993763147657603241, -4010731345091378481, -4258687888114256086, -429860111391304244, -4318544125783476774, -4471769468265919226, -4588065176944445932, -4669765414071774677, -4670558952147294236, -4710259358376415554, -4907784900060021493, -4934593823248165235, -4934821923831720820, -5013288056003569837, -5110268421077583856, -5133973510660140774, -5159515181162633178, -5276029184678521021, -5286266972273013716, -540287937883749850, -5456649087226389873, -5495658378651725051, -5501165049612471047, -5535468008960837763, -5716046948204274477, -5721008906555397374, -5753456205099778029, -5770577886564351775, -5790919034460455792, -5929058167490034525, -5943865033771694477, -608562636816376813, -6109108822129963089, -6140834685397419488, -6170120179807852740, -6179956847809119210, -6245955388738336647, -6286189790411746933, -6299162407942815080, -6315904471665416400, -6364734987085439789, -6419018190136685454, -6451287738650323275, -6547213964231430849, -6548484474977763138, -6549052151069571925, -6698516302891374040, -6872407277556537836, -6901128430416607497, -6935384932230430038, -6937998036050345125, -7031528786091227188, -7106019277455303867, -7119774336125808637, -7191744312745689956, -7225558820114789693, -7349977359560186580, -7422626834116218143, -7431995410347149964, -7466585374358878727, -750799820874518113, -7610594360825096930, -7616154542884798259, -7629884030042898550, -7728553164832596613, -7789353727430662940, -779402220858888622, -7843332228444504745, -7854439386306622129, -815495344326874929, -8338520822777210140, -8649102261484559375, -8796027903791901112, -8898390484583881495, -8923261220379460832, -8943079358447105951, -9050583546904370510, -9080494386502531561, -9139630196350606101, -939306213156730751, -942614916980620152, 1049830730407134075, 1125127596836820990, 1133356003300268705, 1133623932124213230, 1247043876318218235, 1490023295198042772, 1497436537080113324, 1516791905674857253, 1603966065250122923, 1646125781869948326, 1740544126107535998, 1756218012030701589, 1804735370513211257, 1812139850525677114, 1819880350303805394, 1841691686666460445, 1888363141244474676, 2010883847009222978, 2016297526252235227, 2021110586668181290, 2084880932156441613, 2093427980091185166, 2112052724153374980, 2186638483475842552, 2195406825247987731, 2283720951686386464, 23875829161989945, 2521818329391092608, 2522645057607851918, 2524720168145693638, 2541003400153964040, 2650684785592761012, 2723290502273715430, 2808119513098478236, 2821997019638778146, 2891379770529557184, 2907285214187020532, 2963307217336709534, 3061757915053031951, 3122571062025066142, 3128771694670016319, 3130206542424936603, 3197285318974197102, 3218987271686146429, 3329594065878248111, 3331926835266199716, 3526280986313508860, 3542343528340649978, 3589794725284000659, 3610364312437568329, 3701861372719378732, 373747767999916658, 3826422069022675393, 3856151860383170644, 3862031127704782057, 4049338078570571707, 4137865494092400430, 4241199357440741315, 4520402233521387342, 456519309520244643, 4715328215899051522, 4817677510120292180, 497627869146346949, 4995322204306807081, 5030633110404844305, 5038572404428039197, 5042627643214511398, 5281377762367584052, 5494577271219306513, 5530410713928998603, 5537215727145277166, 567120218785751902, 575743986375007756, 5784212620383428248, 5837914425280614947, 5977153680566647690, 5996674261833528410, 6083452088392300601, 6112178449036583235, 6264713703969393897, 6287772759341778176, 6314363909221383341, 6321343658409071604, 6475821468968027456, 6543311556613206558, 6912492987521221000, 6922280123185191829, 694545242943535806, 7183280296372529849, 7306070312091628992, 7412331756775823975, 7518294356359523088, 7567542433462808235, 7589810674525331548, 7637277610587157806, 773319528418720822, 7760484456189230502, 7816590204960057932, 7820991841796591957, 7836345109808448402, 7859570796753174, 8003409347394992259, 8012927612089894493, 8031750463661605171, 8051744553293723603, 8066222841813137181, 8073294271415597086, 8117861819974218900, 817982542709209563, 8198846486095494968, 8214665766962397555, 8277428606113435880, 8279100634451559360, 8316406004646641445, 8367052745804770548, 8373819718798220972, 8439087240414018142, 8444359473760446267, 8449256096936507263, 8717779586961798956, 8912188109780463904, 8920579922439529433, 8951968899880736480, 9043168611036813220, 9044578575232639242, 9045812874827336349, 9140634849238500115, 915715308827014103]
INFO  [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2016-04-12 20:02:15,653 StorageService.java:1924 - Node /169.34.103.150 state jump to shutdown
DEBUG [PendingRangeCalculator:1] 2016-04-12 20:02:15,655 PendingRangeCalculatorService.java:64 - finished calculation for 74 keyspaces in 0ms
ERROR [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2016-04-12 20:02:17,655 StorageService.java:450 - Stopping native transport
INFO  [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2016-04-12 20:02:17,705 Server.java:182 - Stop listening for CQL clients
ERROR [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2016-04-12 20:02:23,219 CassandraDaemon.java:195 - Exception in thread Thread[HintsWriteExecutor:1,5,main]
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriter.newSession(HintsWriter.java:146) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriteExecutor.flushInternal(HintsWriteExecutor.java:221) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriteExecutor.flush(HintsWriteExecutor.java:203) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriteExecutor.lambda$flush$217(HintsWriteExecutor.java:196) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:4649) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriteExecutor.flush(HintsWriteExecutor.java:196) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriteExecutor.access$000(HintsWriteExecutor.java:36) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriteExecutor$FlushBufferPoolTask.run(HintsWriteExecutor.java:155) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.ensureOpen(FileChannelImpl.java:110) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.size(FileChannelImpl.java:300) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriter.newSession(HintsWriter.java:142) ~[apache-cassandra-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        ... 12 common frames omitted
```

I googled around a bit and think the initial exception is caused by the node trying to replay a hint that is very large and it cant load.

I tried to find some parameters that can prevent this, but all I could find was turning off hint handoff (hinted_handoff_enabled) or reducing the time hint handoff runs for (max_hint_window_in_ms). I don't think I can live with an inconsistent cluster and was hoping for an option to split the hints into multiple files, but couldn't find such an option.

Has anyone seen this issue before? Is there a way to split hints into multiple files? How else might I deal with this?

**EDIT:** I hunted through my config and found this

max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128

That seems pretty concervative to me, given the machine I'm running on. If my hints are limited to 128MB then I really dont understand why I have the above exception.

When run on this node nodetool threw an exception. Other nodes were ok, but I only ran nodetool the next morning (12 hours after the exception).

The file the exception complains about is no longer there, but the file name should be ok because I have many other files with similar names (same length). It is interesting the the exception is complaining about a .crc32 file (not a .hint file)

Comment: whats output of nodetool status? there a lot of down nodes?

Comment: Can you please open a bug report on [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA/) for this? This certainly doesn't look like intended behavior and should also not depend on any hint config settings.

Comment: How big is the "bin/../data/hints/389cb0d3-87b9-4221-8352-065e8ce50fdb-1460462523225-1.crc32" file ?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/hints/HintsWriter.java#L110 looks like from jdk? is the filename too long? some crazy filesystem? +1 to jira on this guy...